How to turn off Laravel Context append data for logging
I'm use Laravel Context feature in app (https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/context). And I want to turn off append metadata for Log instance (LoggerInterface) on $debug = false;, and turn on on $debug = true;
How to do it?
I tried to get Logger instance with withoutContext(), but it not working:
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->r = new ResultMsg();
        $this->r->msgPrefix = "POWERDNSSERVICE: ";
        $this->log = $this->debug
            ? Log::channel('dns')
            : Log::withoutContext()->channel('dns');
        $this->logException = Log::channel('dns_exception');
    }

And I found point where Laravel add Context data to log record - Illuminate\Log\LogManager->get($name, ?array $config = null):
    return $record->with(extra: [
        ...$record->extra,
        ...$this->app[ContextRepository::class]->all(),
    ]);


withoutContext() won't work here because Laravel adds the context data after that method runs. Here's what you can do instead:
Create a dedicated channel in config/logging.php without the context processors:
'dns_no_context' => [
    'driver' => 'single',
    'path' => storage_path('logs/dns.log'),
    'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
    'replace_placeholders' => true,
],

Then just switch channels based on your debug flag:
$this->log = $this->debug 
    ? Log::channel('dns')
    : Log::channel('dns_no_context');

That's the quickest way to handle it. If you need something more configurable, you could set it up in your env:
'dns' => [
    'driver' => 'single',
    'path' => storage_path('logs/dns.log'),
    'with_context' => env('LOG_CONTEXT', true),
],

But honestly, the first approach is probably all you need unless you're doing something special with your logging.

Thank you for answer.
Both methods didn't work. I suppose this solution for Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log context — $log->info('Some string', ['some_context' => 'content']);
I looking for how to remove Illuminate\Support\Facades\Context in log.
